# I have error to access local file after build the project?

Tags: reactjs

I want to access local file after build the project, but I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR:
----------
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/maths/media/1546737736816.jpg.
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to put local file inside your build folder.

Comment: it`s not a single file it dynamic uploading multiple files

Comment: please upload the code so we can see how u r uploading images